# IPFS is not a constructor: Nodejs - IPFS/OrbitDB chatroom

Tags: javascript, node.js, publish-subscribe, ipfs, orbitdb

I'm trying to build a Dapp with Nodejs and IPFS/OrbitDB every time, I try to start my App I get the error:

**this.node = new IPFS({**
                    ^

**TypeError: IPFS is not a constructor**

This is my basic code without a specific Swarm:

```
const Ipfs = require('ipfs');
const OrbitDB = require('orbit-db');

class chatroom {
    constructor(IPFS, OrbitDB) {
        this.OrbitDB = OrbitDB;
        this.node = new IPFS({
            preload: {enable: false},
            repo: "./ipfs",
            EXPERIMENTAL: {pubsub: true},
            config: {
                Bootstrap: [],
                Addresses: {Swarm: []}
            }
        });
        this.node.on("error", (e) => {throw (e)});
        this.node.on("ready", this._init.bind(this));
    }
    async _init(){
        this.orbitdb = await this.OrbitDB.createInstance(this.node);
        this.onready();
    }
}

module.exports = exports = new chatroom(Ipfs, OrbitDB);
```

I'm running on the following version of IPFS: ipfs@0.42.0

I tried it also on an empty Nodejs App and there I had the same error also when I added a specific Swarm to connect to.

I would really appreciate your help, thx for your time in advance.

Kind regards

beni

Comment: Try this.node = await IPFS.create()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it now like that:

```
const IPFS = require('ipfs');

async function createNode() {
        let node = await IPFS.create(
            {
                repo: (() => `repo-${Math.random()}`)(),
                    "Addresses": {
                        "Swarm": [
                            "/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/4001"
                        ],
                        "API": "/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/5001",
                        "Gateway": "/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/8080"
                    }
            }
            );
        try {
            await node.start();
            console.log('Node started!');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Node failed to start!', error);
        }
    }
```

(thx @Eugene)